# How to change the position of search box in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, modern-experience, administration, enterprise-search

I have an existing site where its menu showing on left navigation with search box. Here I want to keep the menu bar on the left side but search box on top of the page as below:

[image]

In above screenshot the search box is showing with menus on the left hand side. I want to shift this top of the page as like below.

Anybody can please help with this what workaround I need to apply on the existing site?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try running below PowerShell script:

```
$userName = "user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$passWord = "YourSPOPassword"
$encPassWord = convertto-securestring -String $passWord -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $encPassWord
 
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://yourtenant-admin.sharepoint.com/" -Credentials $cred
 
#Example as below:
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://yourtenant-admin.sharepoint.com/" -Credentials $cred
 
try
{
    $web = Get-PnPWeb
    #0 - Inherit, #1 - AllPages, #2 - ModernOnly, #3 - Hidden enums for Global (Modern Search)
    $web.SearchBoxInNavBar=2
    $web.Update()
    Invoke-PnPQuery
    Write-Host "The changes have been updated successfully." -BackgroundColor Green
}
catch
{
 
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message +"in applying search setting changes!: "
    Write-Host $ErrorMessage -BackgroundColor Red
    Write-Log $ErrorMessage
}
Write-Host "The script execution has been completed successfully."
```

**Source**: [Configure SharePoint search box in office 365 suite bar step by step](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/configure-sharepoint-search-box-in-office-365-suite-bar-step-by-step/)